# Angular 5- Where should logout code sit?

Tags: angular, angular5

It is more of a design question than a programming one.

I want to create Logout Functionality in Angular 5. The logout function will contain following pseudo code:

1. Clear local storage authentication JWT token
2. Redirect to login page

My question is; where should the above code be; In a component or in a service?

I believe, a service should contain logic which interacts with backend only and component should contain presentation logic (Correct me if I am wrong).

As the logout code isn't any logic dealing with backend, it should ideally sit in a component. But, if I have to perform the same operation of the logout somewhere else, it will be easier to call the service and execute the code rather than writing the same two lines again in some different component.

So where should the code really be?

Comment: I would suggest to make it in a service, because there is no need to add a new component with Html (it makes your DOM more complicated) for just one button.

Comment: @SamySammour Thanks for your reply. Anyway I have to write the service calling code in component. So I wonder that can be a point of consideration. Also, the logout button is inside a navbar and I had to create component for navbar because it exists as header in every page.

Comment: Exactly. You can create a component for the header and you write two buttons (login, logout) and hide them using *ngIf.

Comment: It should be in the component. That's because the logout button is in the navbar and so every time you perform a logout you will have to call the service through the navbar component itself. So you wont have to repeat those lines.

Comment: @RachitShroff What if I want to perform the same set of operations in some different scenario? Say on authentication error, I want to clear the authentication token and redirect 
 the user to login page? I will have write the same code again there. If I wrote the code in service, I would just call the service then.

Comment: @SamySammour Thanks for the response. Sure, I can do that. But that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @VinitDivekar writing the function in the header does not mean to write the code in the header. You can make a helper class to make all the steps you want and call it n-times.

Comment: @SamySammour: Yeah. That's a good option. Rather than writing in a service or component itself, the code can be written in  helper class.

Answer (score 0):

you should create logout function inside service like:

```
logout() {
this.localStorageService.remove('currentUser');
this.localStorageService.clear();
this.subject.next(false);
}
```

Call that service method from logout component. don't forget to provide path of logout in your service. To redirect login page you can do:

location.href="/loginUrl";

from logout method.